# How to bind mouseover using knockout in a column in a table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am trying to bind a column in a table for mouseover event, if the cursor is over the column cell (not the column header), it will make the extended details (StrTimeDesc) visible. But when I run it, it will only display the 1st column (Work Date column) then the rest is blank.

here is my view:

```
    <table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>

            <th>Work Date</th>
            <th>Schedule Description</th>


        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody data-bind="foreach: Timesheet_headers">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: workDate"></td>

            <td>
                <div data-bind="event: { mouseover: @parent.enableDetails, mouseout: @parent.disableDetails }">
                    <span data-bind="text: StrSchedDesc"></span>
                </div>
                <div data-bind="visible: IsTog">
                    <span data-bind="text: StrTimeDesc"></span>
                </div>
            </td>       

        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

here is my knockout:

```
var Action =
{

    Timesheet_headers: ko.observableArray([]),
    workDate: ko.observable(),
    Schedule_description: ko.observable(),
    StrSchedDesc: ko.observable(),
    StrTimeDesc: ko.observable(),
    IsTog: ko.observable(false),

    detailsEnabled: ko.observable(false),
    enableDetails: function() {
        this.IsTog(true);
    },
    disableDetails: function() {
        this.IsTog(false);
    }
}
```

apply bindings are already done. I just omitted those parts because SO doesn't allow a post with a lot of codes and less details. If i remove the mouseover binding, the table runs fine. That mouseover bindings came from knockoutjs site.

UPDATE:
here is my class

```
public class Timesheet_header
{

    [Key]
    public System.long AUTO_ID { get; set; }
    public System.Int64 Employee_id { get; set; }
    public System.Int16 Schedule_id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime Work_date { get; set; }

    public string StrSchedDesc { get; set; }
    public string StrTimeDesc { get; set; }
    public bool IsTog { get; set; }

    public Timesheet_header()
    {
        IsTog = false;
    }
}
```

here is my data access (this successfully retrieves all records from the db)

```
public static List<Timesheet_header> GetLogs(long Employee_id, DateTime DateFrom, DateTime DateTo)
{
    var items = new List<Timesheet_header>();
    var command = new SqlCommand();
    try
    {
        command.CommandText = "GetTimeSheetHeaders";
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Employee_id", Employee_id).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateFrom", DateFrom).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateTo", DateTo).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

        DataTable dt = SqlHelper.GetData(command);

        if (dt.Rows.Count <= 0) return items;

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            Timesheet_header item = new Timesheet_header();

            item.AUTO_ID = (row["AUTO_ID"]).GetLong();

            item.Employee_id = (row["Employee_id"]).GetLong();

            item.Work_date = (row["Work_date"]).GetDbDate();                   

            item.StrSchedDesc = row["Schedule_description"].GetString();

            item.StrTimeDesc = " From " + row["Time_from"].GetString() + " - To " + row["Time_to"].GetString();

            items.Add(item);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception s)
    {
        return new List<Timesheet_header>();
    }

    return items;
}
```

I also updated my view and knockout above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`enableDetails` and `disableDetails` should be prefixed with  `$parent` as they are inside a `foreach`. Otherwise knockout will look for those functions inside each `Timesheet_headers` object.

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: Timesheet_headers">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: workDate"></td>

        <td>
            <div data-bind="event: { mouseover: $parent.enableDetails, mouseout: $parent.disableDetails }">
                <span data-bind="text: StrSchedDesc"></span>
            </div>
            <div data-bind="visible: detailsEnabled">
                <span data-bind="text: StrTimeDesc"></span>
            </div>
        </td>       

    </tr>
</tbody>
```

---

This still won't give you the expected result. `workDate`, `Schedule_description`, `StrSchedDesc` `StrTimeDesc` and `IsTog` should be properties of items in `Timesheet_headers` array. You don't need to have that in `Action` object.

There is also a typo here. `O` should be a lowercase in `observable`. Instead of

```
workDate: ko.Observable()
```

you should call

```
workDate: ko.observable()
```

Also, [refer this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46482837/3082296) and this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adigas/6gyp8vgn/). The question is same as yours.

Comment: I've run the app, the hover works, thanks to you. but this is what happened: "Uncaught TypeError: item.IsTog is not a function"

Comment: @Kokombads you need to change your view model like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46482837/3082296): The structure in this question is exactly same as yours. Check the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adigas/6gyp8vgn/)

Comment: it didn't work, but when we recreate what's in the fiddle, it worked. we just abandoned that feature and deployed it nonetheless

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this with pretty simple CSS and keep JavaScript out of this style issue.

Add a class to the table, e.g. `.show-details-on-hover`. Next, add this CSS ruleset:

```
.show-details-on-hover tbody td:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
}

.show-details-on-hover tbody tr:hover td:not(:first-child) {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: I tried doing this. It seems it contradicts with the knockout js's foreach. but when i tried applying this on two div elements, it worked